# CSS v-align absolute div inside relative div that has height determined by img inside

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make a div ("#conteudo_produtos3_txt") vertically align in the middle of another div ("#conteudo_produtos3") that has height determined by a img that is inside of it.

I've tryed using display:table on the container and display:table-cell; vertical-align:middle in the inside div but it doesn't work.

Can I do this using only CSS?

Heres the HTML:

```
<div id="conteudo_produtos3">
    <img width="100%" src="imagens/conteudo_produtos3.jpg" />
    <div id="conteudo_produtos3_txt">
        <h1>b. clue</h1>
        <p>ideal para perfumar ambientes pequenos.<br>
        <br>
        alcance:<br>35 m² (100 m³)<br>
        <br>
        duração do refil:<br>15 a 60 dias;<br>
        <br>
        alimentação:<br>3 pilhas AA;<br>
        <br>
        programação:<br>dias x horas x intervalo de aspersão x volume por aspersão.</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

And the CSS:

```
#conteudo_produtos3{ position:relative; width:100%; display:table; }

#conteudo_produtos3_txt{ position:absolute; left:20%; font-family:moskauLight; text-align:left; display:table-cell; vertical-align:middle; z-index:2; }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try:

```
#conteudo_produtos3_txt {
    font-family:moskauLight; 
    left:20%; 
    position:absolute;
    text-align:left;
    top: 50%; 
    transform: translateY(-50%); 
    z-index:2; 
}
```

Comment: That did it. Thanks!

Comment: @daniel, just want to ask: `z-index:2;` is no use in this case, right?

Comment: Nope @HermanNz - the `display: table;` is also not needed anymore either (for this example).

Comment: ^Reason: #conteudo_produtos3_txt comes after the img in the markup and is automatically set at top

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
#conteudo_produtos3_txt {
position: absolute;
top: 50%;
left: 50%;
tex-align:center;
margin-top: -100px;
margin-left: -200px;
```

`}`

`margin-top` and `margin-left` can be adjusted based on your need.

Comment: however, I have no idea how to center/middle it automatically without adjusting it :D

Answer (score 1):

You could always use the `calc()` function on the margin-top property of the inside div. Set it to be 50% minus half of the image height.

For instance, if the height of the image is 300px, you could set the margin-top property to

```
#conteudo_produtos3_txt {
  margin-top: calc(50% - 150px);
}
```

That should vertically align it within the image.

Answer (score 0):

You should use padding:auto for outer div or margin:auto for child div